# Prevent array from XSS

Tags: arrays, xss

i have this to protect from xss

html//

```
<input class="form-control"  type="text" name="pc_accesoires[]">
```

/// PHP

```
$pc_acc = $_POST["pc_accesoires"];
$accesoires = array();
  foreach($pc_acc as $key => $value){
  $accesoires[] = $value; 
}
```

and after i have a prepared sql to insert $accesoires into table , all work fine , no sql injection but this code is vulnerable to XSS attack

How can i protect this variable ?? i have try htmlentities & htmlspecialchar bu i receved an error be caus htmlentities && htmlspecialchar  accepte a string but not array

Answer (score 0):

Use a function to iterate over the object, check if it's an array or not, and sanitize accordingly. Something like this should work:

```
function htmlspecialchars_obj(&$variable)
{
    foreach ($variable as &$value)
    {
        // Check if item is an array or object, if so call this function recursively.
        if (is_array($value) || is_object($value))
        {
            htmlspecialchars_obj($value);
        }
        else
        {
            // Otherwise, sanitize this item and continue iteration.
            $value = htmlspecialchars($value);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: this passes by reference and modifies the parameter you give it rather than returning an edited copy.

Here's an example of how to use the function:

```
// Initialise an array/object (whatever needs to be protected).

$myVariable = array();
$myVariable['xss'] = "<script>alert('xss attack');</script>";
$myVariable['noxss'] = "Just a plain string.";

// Use the function:

htmlspecialchars_obj($myVariable);

// Now $myVariable is safe to print:

foreach($myVariable as $key => $value){
   print($value); 
}
```

Here is an example using the code you provided:

```
    $pc_acc = $_POST["pc_accesoires"];

    htmlspecialchars_obj($pc_acc);

    $SQLInsertReq = "INSERT INTO maintenance (pc_accesoires) VALUES ( ? )";

    $InsertRerSTMT = $connect->stmt_init();

    if(!$InsertRerSTMT->prepare($SQLInsertReq)){

         $ro = $InsertRerSTMT->error;

         echo $ro;

         exit();
    }
    else {

      $accesoires = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $accesoires);

      $accesoires = implode(',', $accesoires)

      $InsertRerSTMT->bind_param('s', $accesoires);

      $InsertRerSTMT->execute();
   }


    function htmlspecialchars_obj(&$variable)
    {
        foreach ($variable as &$value)
        {
            // Check if item is an array or object, if so call this function recursively.
            if (is_array($value) || is_object($value))
            {
                htmlspecialchars_obj($value);
            }
            else
            {
                // Otherwise, sanitize this item and continue iteration.
                $value = htmlspecialchars($value);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: No problem - please mark as accepted answer if it does what you need. Please also delete your other answers too - that kind of thing will anger the powers that govern this site :)

Comment: sorry is not work :/ the fields dynamicly added do not insred in to mysql table

Comment: the problem will be elsewhere in your code as I know that function works, but I'm pleased you got it working, nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

Finely i have secure my fields right ther

```
    $pc_acc = $_POST["pc_accesoires"];

    $accesoires = array();
    foreach($pc_acc as $key => $value){
        $accesoires[] = htmlspecialchars($value);
    }
```

so simple !!!!!!!